# I can't use & tabs in the `align` environment while using it inside a custom environment

Tags: tables, environments, align

I've got a custom environment made for problem sets, and it uses a `tabular` to align the question number and question body. When I try to use `&` to group parts of an equation together - like if I want to align the `=` sign across multiple equations, I get compile errors. Is there any way I can fix this behavior? I'm all for getting rid of the tabular in my environment if I can use some other method to align the question body in a way that's visually equivalent to what I have now...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}

\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{100}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{m{\mylen}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mylen-3\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
  \arabic{problem}. & \ifx\relax#1\relax \else\textbf{#1}\\[1mm]&\fi
  }
  {\end{tabular}\ignorespacesafterend\medskip}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{problem}
    \begin{align*}
          =&\int_{1}^{3}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ dx\\
          =&\left.\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+ln\lvert x\rvert\;\right|_{1}^{3}
    \end{align*}
  \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `tabular` instead of `align`. `&` is used both  by `align` and `tabular`. Similarly  `\\ `.

Comment: @HarishKumar Sadly, `tabular` doesn't work either. But I don't want to do that - I want bo be able to use the functionality of `align` or `gather` inside of my custom environment.

Comment: Hm, it seems to me, you just want a label on the start of the line of the length of `100`, and that what follows in a minipage of the remaining width. Which in turn just is a simple always resuming `enumerate` which can be set up with `enumitem` to work kind of the same way. If not you need to explain better what you want, how it should look like etc.

Comment: I get compile errors _no matter what_ I put into your 'problem' environment. Is this really an `align` issue? (Ping, @Qrrbrbirlbel.)

Comment: I had forgotten about this question, actually - I had the problem solved via another post in a semi-related issue. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in my comment, here a solution (?) with `enumitem`.

The list `qrr@problem` is created with the label format `\arabic*.` (where `*` stands for the counter internally used).

The `problem` environment then uses the `qrr@problem` environment to automatically add the first (and in your case only) `\item`, either without or with the text given in the *mandatory* argument. (The optional first argument is forwarded to the `qrr@problem` list.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools, enumitem}

\newlist{qrr@problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[qrr@problem,1]{label=\arabic*.,resume}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{problem}[2][]{%
    \qrr@problem[#1]\item\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\relax\else\textbf{#2}\fi
}{%
    \endqrr@problem
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{problem}{}
    \begin{align*}
          y & = \int_{1}^{3}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ dx\\
            & = \left.\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+ln\lvert x\rvert\;\right|_{1}^{3}
    \end{align*}
  \end{problem}

  \begin{problem}{Next problem, same equation}
    \begin{align*}
          y & = \int_{1}^{3}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ dx \\
            & = \left.\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+ln\lvert x\rvert\;\right|_{1}^{3}
    \end{align*}
  \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `\ln` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I got from somebody else while trying to fix another issue related to this badly designed environment. It had the effect of also fixing this issue.

I've included two extra environment definitions just to allow my example to work, since it was pulled from a homework assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{
  \refstepcounter{problem}%
  \begin{list}{\arabic{problem}.}
              {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{100}%
               \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
              }
    \item \ifx\relax#1\relax \else\textbf{#1}\\[1mm]\fi
    }
    {\end{list}}

\newenvironment{parts}
  {\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\def\qed{\ensuremath{\square}} % <-QED Symbol
\newenvironment{solution}{%  <-Solution
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \itshape{Solution:}\\}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill\qed\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{problem}[Evaluate the integrals:]
    \begin{parts}
      \item $\displaystyle\int\sec^4{x}\ dx$
      \begin{solution}
        \begin{align*}
          \int\sec^2{x}\ dx&=\int\sec^2{x}\sec^2{x}\ dx\\
          &=\int\left(\tan^2{x}+1\right)\sec^2{x}\ dx\\
          &=\int\tan^2{x}\sec^2{x}\ dx+\int\sec^2{x}\ dx\\
          &=\frac{1}{3}\left[\tan^3{x}+3\tan{x}\right]+C
        \end{align*}
      \end{solution}
    \end{parts}
  \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]